# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tendo este erro em meu código: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null", procurei por ele no Google, tentei as soluções apresentadas mas nenhuma funcionou.

cadastro-cuidador.js:

```
function HabilitarUpload() {
    if (document.getElementById(declaracaoCuidador).checked) {
        document.getElementById(inputCertificado).removeAttribute("hidden");
    } else {
        document.getElementById(inputCertificado).setAttribute("hidden", "true");
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Cuidadores</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script language="JavaScript" src="./js/cadastro-cuidador.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-cuidador">
            <p>
                <label class="container">Sou um cuidador
                <input type="checkbox" id="declaracaoCuidador" onclick="HabilitarUpload()">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </p>
            <p id="pInputCertificado" hidden="true">Insira seu certificado (.pdf, .png ou .jpg)
            <input type="file" name="img-certificado" id="inputCertificado"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Já tentei colocar o script no final do body, mas não resolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você acabou se esquecendo de colocar os `ids` que está buscando entre aspas:

```js
function HabilitarUpload() {
    if (document.getElementById('declaracaoCuidador').checked) {
        document.getElementById('inputCertificado').removeAttribute("hidden");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('inputCertificado').setAttribute("hidden", "true");
    }
}
```